# How do I get the indices of a reverse sorted list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sorting

Say I have array:

```
A = [3, 3, 2, 2, 4]
```

The indices of the sorted list (ascending) would be:

```
[2, 3, 0, 1, 4]
```

I want the reverse sorted list (descending):

```
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Note that the reverse sorted list is not a direct reverse of the sorted list.

I would have used numpy; however, if I do this:

```
indices = np.argsort(A)[::-1]

# This gives: indices = [4, 1, 0, 3, 2]
# But I want: indices = [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Thus, how do I get the indices of the reverse sorted list that I want? Or is there some way to do this with numpy?

Thanks!

Comment: What about `argsort(-A)`?

Comment: How did you end up with 0 and then 1 as the second and third output elements, considering both elements at those indices are 3?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What is the negative sign doing to the A?

Comment: @VickConan: it maps `3` on `-3`, etc. So that the largest element in `A` is the smallest in `-A`, etc.

Comment: @Divakar If 2 elements are the same, like 3 and 3, I want the index of the first element.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yup, OP simply needs to use `mergsort` to keep the order that way : `(-A).argsort(kind='mergesort')`.

Comment: @Divakar: or apparently just `kind='stable'` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `np.argsort(..)` the negative array here, like:

```
>>> np.argsort(-np.array([3, 3, 2, 2, 4]), kind='mergesort')
array([4, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

or since [numpy-1.15](/questions/tagged/numpy-1.15), you can use:

```
>>> np.argsort(-np.array([3, 3, 2, 2, 4]), kind='stable')
array([4, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```